# How Wordpress theme WpBakery can expose component and page data as JSON rather than full HTML content via REST api?

Tags: wordpress, rest, headless, wpbakery

Currently WpBakery exposes the content via REST api's, but it exposes the full HTML content of page.
But for us to build Headless front end in React or Angular we would need structured page/component data in Rest api as JSON, not the FULL HTML content.

Does anyone knows any plugin or extension or any custom code that can help us to expose just page/component structured json Data via REST api with WpBakery plugin on wordpress?

We tried using the page data using REST api enablement on WPBakery plugin. But we get all the data in this format -

```
"content":{"rendered":"<div> <h1>Hello Page Header 2</h1> <p>Body content-1</p> </div>"}
```

But i am expecting data to be exposed as JSON structure for each component inside a page something like this format -

```
{"content":{"outer":{:body":"Body content-1","header":"Hello Page Header 2"}}}
```

and then my React app can construct components for "outer" and "header" to bind data from JSON.
But WPBakery should give me only content of components/pages in REST api.